# Cross-page posting with target _blank leaves source page unfunctional

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to describe it in as few steps as possible:
I have **Page1.aspx** with lot of controls, and Preview and Save button among those. I also have **Page2.aspx** that is the redirection target of a Preview Button click.

Since I need all the controls selections from Page1 to draw a preview on Page2 the redirection is done with setting Preview's `PostBackUrl`.
I also must have preview shown on a new tab or window so I used `onClientClick="aspnetForm.target='_blank'"` for Preview button definition.

Save button-click callback, after storing data to a database does redirection to some Page0.aspx (initial list of reports - the subject of the code)

Preview button works fine - a preview renders in a new tab, but when I go to the old tab and click on Save, I see from debugger, that firstly Page2.aspx(?) and secondly Page1.aspx are loaded. Then all the data is stored in the db, but though Page0 redirection is executed Page1.aspx stays loaded in the browser.

I have no idea what processes are behind this. Could one who knows give me an insight? Or if you consider my approach impossible to implement give some idea how to do the same?

If it's of importance, everything on the Page1 is located in an update panel.

Thank you very much for replying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ASP.NET there are basically zero (0) circumstances in which you will ever send form data from one page to another. Although what exactly you are trying to accomplish is vague, you can consider some of the following:

- Isolate unique operations/systems to a single page. If you have something like a User Profile, don't have three different aspx pages; just use a single page for the user or admin to manage that data / functions. Postback events are your friend.
- Understand the difference between ViewState and traditional form data. I'm guessing that if you're trying to post form data from one page to another, you probably don't understand the point of ViewState. Using a single page to maintain temporary data that the user is currently working with is a great use for ViewState. If you want the data to appear on another page then you need to consider the data from the previous page as final and thus should be saved to a database or some other medium.

These are just some general guidelines because there is no exact answer to your problem without saying something generic like "You're doing it wrong." I would recommend starting by never again trying to post form data from one aspx page to another.

Comment: The scenario is: Page1 is for creating report template for a very large web system - contains numerous rows with multiple dropdowns and inputs. The purpose of the preview button is for user to get a drawn report (in a new page - already written page with existing functionality) for the current selections, and if the template is constructed well save the template to the db (click on Save).

Further more, all the mentioned controls are actually part of a user control, included in several pages (Page1.aspx being one of them)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this Asp.Net principle, I will have it on my mind from now, but here I'm constrained to the existing frame.
I'm not sure it's constructive here to, on Preview click, save to the db all the temporary values and use them on Page2 later? (principle 2 you stated)

The best help would be insight in why both pages are loaded on a postback from the old tab and the tab is messed up? If would help to handle the issue or else I'm up to some broader refactorization.

Thank you once more

Comment: Yes, you are exactly right. Save the data you need to on page 1 and if you need a preview button, use the querystring to send data to the next page or another means like you mentioned (saving to the database and then loading the data on the other page).

Comment: The principle you stated is right.
I tried different things but on the end it was the easiest to store the Page1 data in the session.
What I did was adding dynamically, by JQuery (on Preview click) a new form to the Page1.aspx, whose only purpose is to call Page2. It's target is set to _blank, so it will open in a new window.
Page2 expects data from the session